# PHP - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) in

Tags: php, mysql

Bom dia! Estou com este código e faço sustentação do site, do nada este erro começou a aparecer :(

```
public function getUrlcliente($cliente_id) {

        $parametro = "cliente_id=" . (int)$cliente_id;
        $url_cliente = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT query as indice, keyword as url FROM url_cliente WHERE query = '" . $parametro . "'");

        if (empty($url_cliente)) {
            $url = "Erro - URL cliente não cadastrada";
        }
        else {
            foreach ($url_cliente as $row) {
                $url = $row->url;
            }

        if ($url_cliente->num_rows) {
                    return $url;
                }
        else
                {
                    return "Erro-Url inexistente";
                }
}

public function getcliente($cliente_id) {   // Dá erro nesta linha ** Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) in ....

    $url_ex = $this->getUrlcliente($cliente_id);

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT *, p.name AS name, p.image, '" . $this->getUrlcliente($cliente_id) . "' AS url_externa FROM cliente p";
    if ($query->num_rows) {
        return array(
            'cliente_id'       => $query->row['cliente_id'],
            'name'             => $query->row['name'],
            'image  '      => $query->row['image'],
            'url_externa'      => $query->row['url_externa'],
            'meta_description' => $query->row['meta_description'],
            'meta_keyword'     => $query->row['meta_keyword'],
            'tag'              => $query->row['tag']
        );
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Não consigo encontrar o motivo do erro.

Comment: Veja se isso te ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13341391/6101515

Comment: @JuniorNunes, tudo bem que ele não postou o código todo, mas se o erro ocorre na segunda função, podemos crer que tudo está dentro de uma classe, além disso, está claro que falta é fechar as chaves em algum ponto...

Comment: @KennyRafael verdade!

Comment: Erro simples de digitação é fora de escopo, e já tem duas respostas explicando o erro. É desatenção ao digitar. Note que você foi ajudado, só não faz sentido largar aberta a postagem por causa deste tipo de erro. Tem duas respostas explicando o problema, e um comentário logo acima. Se indentar o código certinho fica evidente que você não fechou um dos colchetes.

Comment: Sou novo aqui no fórum, não entendia como funcionava. Desculpem.

Comment: @MSergio não precisa se desculpar, tá tudo ok e vc nao fez nada errado, só estamos explicando pra vc entender a razão, e entender que não é nada pessoal, só organização. Estamos aqui pra ajudar. Não se sinta desincentivado a perguntar, o fechamento nesse caso foi só uma consequência natural, e não uma reprovação. Se quiser dar uma lida depois, tem a [help] com vários assuntos que podem ajudar a se situar, e também o [FAQ da comunidade](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/699) no nosso site 'meta", que é o site onde se discute o funcionamento do site principal.

Comment: @Bacco muito obrigado. Estou mandando outra dúvida. rsrs Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está faltando fechar o `else`, logo após o fechamento do `foreach`.

Veja como está seu código:

```
    if (empty($url_cliente)) {
        $url = "Erro - URL cliente não cadastrada";
    }
    else {
        foreach ($url_cliente as $row) {
            $url = $row->url;

    }
```

Faça essa correção:

```
  else {
       foreach ($url_cliente as $row) {
            $url = $row->url;
       } // fecha o foreach
  } // fecha o else
```

**Dica**: Indente melhor o seu código. Eu descobri o erro de síntaxe graças a um plugin que uso no Sublime Text que mostra erros de sintaxe em um script PHP, mas se foi complicado de achar por causa da falta de organização das disposições das chaves.

Comment: Na verdade o `foreach` está fechado, faltava basicamente fechar a função realmente, a menos que tenha alguma lógica muito diferente da que parece ser...

Comment: @KennyRafael é verdade, na verdade o que estava faltando fechar era o `else`. A indenização do código dele me confundiu todo :\

Answer (score 3):

Está faltando fechar uma `{}` na sua primeira função!

```
public function getUrlcliente($cliente_id) {

    $parametro = "cliente_id=" . (int)$cliente_id;
    $url_cliente = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT query as indice, keyword as url FROM url_cliente WHERE query = '" . $parametro . "'");

    if (empty($url_cliente)) {
        $url = "Erro - URL cliente não cadastrada";
    }
    else {
        foreach ($url_cliente as $row) {
            $url = $row->url;
        }

        if ($url_cliente->num_rows)
            {
                return $url;
            }
        else
            {
                return "Erro-Url inexistente";
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Na primeira função não, no `foreach`...

Comment: Com essa indentação torta da pergunta, tudo que sabemos é que falta um `}`, o lugar é questionável :)

Comment: Sim, deduzi dessa forma pela lógica da lógica...ba dum tss

Mas realmente, DEFICIL!